# How to do liquibase multiple modifyDataType in YAML

Tags: mysql, migration, yaml, liquibase

How can i change and do multiple modifyDataType in a yaml with liquibase? this does not work. I tried several other combinations and there are no example I could find. thank you

```
- changeSet:
    id: update-contact-fieldlength-02-20-2017
    author: pat.xxx@xx.com
    changes:
    - modifyDataType:
        columnName: first_name
        newDataType: varchar(100)
        schemaName: embark
        tableName: contact
   - modifyDataType:
       columnName: last_name
        newDataType: varchar(100)
        schemaName: embark
        tableName: contact
```

Changed display format from comment below

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop: After much research we found that I did have the correct yaml structure. The issue was a conflict that this yaml reveals with some unit tests under Windows. We are trying to find the root cause but at least this question is answered now.